# ¿Cómo ofuscar código Php?

Tags: php

Para poder "ocultar" código fuente de un programa, ¿Se puede ofuscar pero que se siga corriendo correctamente?

Por decir, si tengo una función

```
function funcion (){
  echo 'ejemplo';
}
```

Pueda transformarla a:

aosdniw2$#%2nsndojw ....

por decir un ejemplo, caracteres al aleatorios que a la vista no tengan ningún sentido, pero **que se pueda seguir ejecutando correctamente**

Comment: Mira está pregunta http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/33650/deofuscar-c%c3%b3digo-php y verás un ejemplo de como se hace. Ese usuario tienen el problema contrario al tuyo.

Comment: Sí, de hecho :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hay multitud de "ofuscadores" disponibles para PHP. Aun así, ni siquiera eso impedirá que un usuario pueda "leer" tu código si tiene acceso a él. Soluciones como [Dezender](http://dezender.net/), entre otras, hacen muy bien su trabajo a la hora de restaurar código php previamente ofuscado.

Si puede ejecutarlo, puede leer su código, ten eso presente.

Como opinión personal, aunque SO no vaya de eso, te diré que compartir tu código con la comunidad siempre es más beneficioso que ocultarlo. Las posibilidades de que tu trabajo mejore son infinitas.

Si hay alguna razón de peso para que quieras hacerlo, una razón comercial por ejemplo, lo mejor es que busques a un abogado y generes una licencia de uso de tu aplicación.

Comment: Completamente de acuerdo, además de que ofuscar el código será doble trabajo para el interprete de PHP.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario. Como dices, es con fines comerciales y como sabemos, las licencias no son suficientes. Hablo de código que pueda comprometer la seguridad de una aplicación, he allí la necesidad.

Comment: Puedes intentarlo con http://www.fopo.com.ar/, aunque si haces una búsqueda en google encontrarás cientos de opciones.